# Session variable is not available across routes

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I am facing this problem from long time and finally I decided to post it here.
I am storing the session variable in one route and when I try to access it from other route it is not defined.

**server.js file**

```
var express=require('express');
app=express();
var port=process.env.PORT || 8080;
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var router=express.Router();
var appRoutes=require('./routes/api')(router);
var session=require('express-session');
var MongoStore=require('connect-mongo')(session);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(session({
    secret:'hardik',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true,
    store: new MongoStore({mongooseConnection:mongoose.connection})
}));
app.listen(port,function(){
    console.log('running on port '+port);
});
```

**api.js**

```
router.post('/authenticate',function(req,res){
    var token=jwt.sign({
        email:req.body.email
    },secret);
    var profile=req.body.profile;
    req.session.token=token;
    console.log(req.session);
    console.log(req.session.token);
}
```

and after this it will show the token if I log just below that line but in any other routes if I try to log it, it gives undefined.
any help is invited.

Comment: you should store your token in local storage on frontend and should pass that token in authorization in headers

Answer (score 0):

If you are using passport after user login you can match all route with * and store the session with req.locals

```
app.get('*', function(req, res, next){
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  next();
});
```

Add this line before you start your server

Comment: I am not using passport after user login. for now I am storing token variable in local storage but I have just decided to store it in session. any idea for this?

Comment: Ok. If you want to use local storage you cab use HTML5 local storage to store your data, Oauth is another option.